# How to print number from array?

Tags: javascript

I want to print out the number of a characters there are in the array. However when i use console.log the error I get is that what I'm trying to print is not a number. I've tried casting the contents to an integer but that doesn't seem to work. How can I print the contents of the array as a number?

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    let arr = new Array(26);
    for(let i = 0; i < s.length;i++) {
        arr[s.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]++;
    }
    console.log(arr[Number('a'.charCodeAt(0)) - Number('a'.charCodeAt(0))]);
    while(arr['a'.charCodeAt(0)- 'a'.charCodeAt(0)] > 0) {
        console.log('a');
        arr['a'.charCodeAt(i)- 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]--;
    }
}
```

The response i get is "NaN" but it sure just print out the number of a's in the string.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do in while loop ? and `arr['a'.charCodeAt(i)- 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]--`

Comment: Can you share the input and the expected output of your function? It's hard to figure out what the code is supposed to be doing right now.

Comment: When you initialize `arr = new Array(26)` the value at each index is undefined.Thus, when you do `arr[s.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]++` you are essentially doing undefined++, which becomes NaN. Make sure each element in your array is initialized to 0 first.

Comment: Use `arr = new Array(26).fill(0)` to avoid all the `NaN`, but when posting an answer, I'm a bit perplexed by the `while` area as well as the above commenters and couldn't finish beyond this. `i` is not in scope and the logic is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat cryptic question, but it seems like you are looking to find how many instances of the letter 'a' are in the string argument.

Try:

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    return s
        // include uppercase A's
        .toLowerCase()
        // split string into array of characters
        .split('')
        // filter out all non-'a' characters
        .filter(char => 
            char == 'a'
        )
        // find how many characters are left
        .length;
}
console.log(vowelsAndConsonants(`a sentence with a lot of A's`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for, anyway:

```js
vowelsAndConsonants = function(s) {
 // Vowels
 const V = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
 // remove all the characters that are not vowels or consonants (punctuation, spaces, accented characters, numbers, ...)
 const S = new String(s).replace(/[^a-z]/gmi, '');
 // counters initialization
 let characters = {};
 let vowels = cons = 0;
 const firstCharacter = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
 const lastCharacter = 'z'.charCodeAt(0);
 for(let i = firstCharacter; i <= lastCharacter; i++) {
  characters[String.fromCharCode(i)] = 0;
 }
 // start counting
 let char;
 for(let i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
  char = S[i].toLowerCase();
  characters[char]++;
  // check if it is a vowel or a consonant
  if(V.indexOf(char) !== -1)
   vowels++;
  else
   cons++;
 }
 return {
  characters: characters,
  vowels: vowels,
  cons: cons
 };
}

// test
const counter = vowelsAndConsonants("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
console.log(counter);
```

RESULT

```
{
  "characters": {
    "a": 7,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 4,
    "d": 8,
    "e": 11,
    "f": 0,
    "g": 2,
    "h": 0,
    "i": 11,
    "j": 0,
    "k": 0,
    "l": 6,
    "m": 6,
    "n": 5,
    "o": 10,
    "p": 3,
    "q": 1,
    "r": 6,
    "s": 6,
    "t": 9,
    "u": 6,
    "v": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  },
  "vowels": 45,
  "cons": 57
}
```